# Moved classes in new package, can't access resources

Tags: java, resources, package

I have created a 14class java project. So far I have been using default-package.
Today I have moved all my classes using: Refactor - Move, and I created a new package.

After doing that, I cannot access my resources. Running my MainForm class I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
        at com.anreas.mls.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:279)
        at com.anreas.mls.MainForm$1.run(MainForm.java:48)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

EDIT: Line 279 of MainForm:

```
        btnHelp.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("images/help.png")));
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

If anyone knows how I this I would really appreciate it!

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How are you accessing these resources? Anyway you should probably read similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception

Comment: could you post **line no 279** of `MainForm` class of `package com.anreas.mls`

Comment: is your main class in the same package as others? could you post a snapshot of your directory structure?

Comment: @Blip updated my question and added the line.

Comment: @RahulSharma updated question and added a snapshot, all classes are in my package.

Comment: Try with `.getResource("/images/help.png")`

Comment: does your package `com.anreas.mls` has a directory `images` that contains the file `help.png`? if not place the same and it will work fine

Comment: @Pshemo why did this work? I didn't have this issue with Default-Package. Can you please my kind sir explain to me why this was the solution?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String- In short if you start with `/` resource will be searched starting from root directory of your project, otherwise you will start from package which contains class on which you invoked `getResource`.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you so much man. made my day :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is what Pshemo commented in my question.

.getResource("/images/help.png")

[image]